# Send a message after the user stops responding through WatsonX Assistant

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I've been using WatsonX Assistant to help solve some user issues through WhatsApp.
However, due to the session duration limitations, the user has a set limit of time (1 hour in this case)

I want to create a flow where if it's been 20 minutes since the user's last message, to say something like "*are you there?*", however, I cannot seem to find a way to do so through the user interface.

I tried using Expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible. When we will support it i will update this answer.

Fyi, you can change the session duration from 1h to less. The only difference would be that if the user sends another message it will start from scratch.